# Given a binary string of length n and a function which changes each digit with odds 1/n. Find the odds that more 0s are changed than 1s.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, conditional-probability

Given a binary string of length n with i number of 1s and each digit is changed to the other, independently, with probability $\frac{1}{n}$. What is the probability that more 0s will be changed than 1s?

My approach so far:
a - number of 0s flipped,
b - number of 1s flipped,
and $p = \frac{1}{n}$.

$$P(a>b) =  \sum_{k=0}^{i} (P(a>k)P(b=k))$$
$$ =\sum_{k=0}^{i} ((\sum_{w=k+1}^{n-i} P(a=w))P(b=k)) $$
$$ = \sum_{k=0}^{i} ((\sum_{w=k+1}^{n-i} {(n-i) \choose w} p^{w}(1-p)^{n-i-w}) {i \choose k}p^{k} (1-p)^{i-k}) $$

At this point, I feel it is too complicated and I cannot seem to simplify it any further. Did I go wrong somewhere? Is there an easier method? Can it be further simplified?
If not is there any good lower bound we can deduce? Any help would be appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Not sure the rules are clear. Do you mean that exactly one is switched, and that it could be any of them with equal chance? Or do you mean that each character independently switches with that probability?

Comment: Oh, I should have clarified. Each character is switched independently with probability $\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: So, then I think it's an ugly mess.  If the numbers are large you can use normal approximations to simplify it.

Comment: Could you tell me how I can do that?

Comment: Set up a double integral. Joint distribution is just the product.   But the numbers do have to be large.